# How is threading.Lock.acquire() blocking in this implementation?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-3.x, python-multithreading

On Python 3.4.3, I'm failing to understand how the [threading.Lock.acquire()](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/_dummy_thread.py#L102) blocks until the lock status is set to unlocked.

`threading.Lock` seems to be an implementation of `_dummy_thread.LockType` linked above.

This code seems to be doing anything but blocking. If I am correct, where is the implementation of the blocking behavior of a threading.Lock?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you linked is a *dummy* implementation of the interface. That means it does nothing. No blocking. It is used when you do not actually use threads, to ease the writing of code that can work both in threaded and non-threaded environments.

The function you want to look at is in [threading.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/threading.py#L115)

It does not have much though, as the actual implementation is done in C, in the `_thread` module. It is selected at python interpreter's compile time. You can find here the implementation for [pthread](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/thread_pthread.h) and for [windows](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Python/thread_nt.h).

Namely, the Windows implementation uses [WaitForSingleObjectEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms687036(v=vs.85).aspx) and pthread implementation uses [sem_timedwait](http://linux.die.net/man/3/sem_timedwait) under the hood.

Comment: On the link provided, I fail to see where it's blocking. Could you to explain?

Comment: I added some more details, including where the actual behaviors is implemented. It's in a C submodule.

Comment: Exactly what I was hope to find!